# Нужна помощь с SQL запросом. Не могу определить автора с самой высокой средней оценкой книг

Tags: sql

Всем привет! Мне нужна помощь с SQL. У меня есть несколько таблиц, между ними связи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно определить автора с самой высокой средней оценкой книг — учитываем только книги с 50 и более оценками. Пишу вот такой запрос:

```
   SELECT a.author_id,
    ROUND(AVG(ra.rating), 2) AS avg_rating,
    COUNT(ra.rating_id)

    FROM
    books AS b,
    authors AS a,
    ratings AS ra

    WHERE
    b.book_id = ra.book_id AND b.author_id = a.author_id

    GROUP BY 
    a.author_id

    HAVING COUNT(ra.rating_id) >= 50

    ORDER BY count DESC
```

Получается, что я считаю HAVING COUNT(ra.rating_id) >= 50 по авторам, а мне нужно по книгам. Подскажите как поправить запрос? Чтобы я получил автора с самой высокой средней оценкой книг (учитываем только книги с 50 и более оценками) Спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужны два разных уровня группировки. Без подзапроса (возможно, в форме CTE) тут не обойтись. Кроме того, неясно, существуют ли книги с 2 и более авторами, и как их учитывать.

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях пробуйте рассмотреть задачу по частям. Вот для начала средние оценки книг с 50 и более оценками (у меня тут MySQL).

```
select
    `book_id`,
    avg(`rating`) as `book_rating_avg`
from `ratings`
group by `book_id`
having count(*) >= 50
```

Результат этого запроса можно рассматривать как таблицу. Если с такой таблицей сджойнить запрос в books, то можно будет группировать по авторам.

```
select
    `books`.`author_id`,
    avg(`book_avg_ratings`.`book_rating_avg`) as `author_rating_avg`
from `books`
inner join (
    select
        `book_id`,
        avg(`rating`) as `book_rating_avg`
    from `ratings`
    group by `book_id`
    having count(*) >= 50
) as `book_avg_ratings` on
     `book_avg_ratings`.`book_id` = `books`.`id`
group by `books`.`author_id`
order by `author_rating_avg` desc
```

Конечно, всё это добро работает довольно медленно. Если данных много, а запрос надо выполнять часто, то имеет смысл рассчитывать количество оценок и среднюю оценку книги при добавлении оценки, например.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог Ваш ответ, нашла ошибку: не `book_avg_ratings`.`book_id` = `books`.`id`, а book_avg_ratings`.`book_id` = `books`.book_id.`, тогда все работает